# Postgres JSONB equivalent to MongoDB $ifNull (aggregation)

Tags: mongodb, postgresql, supabase

I am in a process of using Postgres database (Supabase) instead of MongoDB. Sorry I am still rather new to Postgres, worked only with MongoDB previously.

For some columns it is still preferable and reasonable to use JSONB.

Is there any equivalent to MongoDB [$ifNull (aggregation)](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/) with replacement expression value?

*In MongoDB the $ifNull expression evaluates input expressions for null values and returns the first non-null input expression value found or a replacement expression value if all input expressions evaluate to null.*

Unfortunately I have zero success in Postgres, in MongoDB it was really easy.

My piece of code in MongoDB was as this:

```
$ifNull: [
    `$$proposedamendments.name_lang.${l}`,
    "$$proposedamendments.name_lang.en",
    "$$proposedamendments.name_lang.fr",
]
```

Thank very much to all Postgres experts for their help.

Comment: Have you checked out [coalesce](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html)?

Comment: Thank you very much. Seems like a way to go. Will test it later today and give feedback.

Comment: @ray It seems COALESCE is not directly accessible [Supabase SQL to JS api](https://supabase.com/docs/guides/database/sql-to-api). So in that case I may use [CREATE VIEW](https://supabase.com/blog/postgresql-views) in Supabase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you very much @ray for the tip.
This code worked for me

```sql
SELECT COALESCE(name_lang->>'${l}', name_lang->>'en', name_lang->>'fr') FROM "TABLE_NAME";
```

(${l} is added dynamically from client)